# Could login remember tags chosen?

Tags: feature-request, bug

I started posting a question ([Problems installing Windows 10 under VMware Fusion on El Capitan Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/994601/problems-installing-windows-10-under-vmware-fusion-on-el-capitan-mac)) and filled out the title, body of question, and tags before seeing that I was not logged in. I opened up the login page in a separate question and logged in.

Both the page after I logged in, and the original page after I reloaded, had 100% of the title and body of my questions, but not the then three tags I had added.

Could the system preserve any tags chosen alongside with the title and question body if it is saved and restored for any of the various ways SO restores a (perhaps incomplete) page as last stored?